# How to run NumPy code on the GPU with Numba

Tags: python, numba

I've developed several codes with high matrix implication; those run quite well but since I spent some extra money in GPU, I'd like take advantage from it... ;-) I've tryed in several configurations from numba manual, but clearly something is missing .. Why I receive an error when try to execute some functions in Cuda (nvidia gtx 1050)?
Would be numba or eighter other module, how can I let execute a portion of code (which require strong parallelization) into GPU ?

```
from numba import types
from numba.extending import intrinsic
from numba import jit, cuda
from numba import vectorize

@jit
def calculate_portfolio_return(returns, weights):
    portfolio_return = np.sum(returns.mean()*weights)*252
    print("Expected Portfolio Return:", portfolio_return)
    
@jit
def calculate_portfolio_risk(returns, weights):
    portfolio_variance = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(returns.cov()*252,weights)))
    print("Expected Risk:", portfolio_variance)

@jit
def generate_portfolios(weights, returns):

    preturns = []
    pvariances = []

    for i in range(10000):
        # weights = np.random.random(len(stocks_portfolio))
        weights = np.random.random(data.shape[1])
        weights/=np.sum(weights)
        preturns.append(np.sum(returns.mean()*weights)*252)
        pvariances.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(returns.cov()*252,weights))))

    preturns = np.array(preturns)
    pvariances = np.array(pvariances)
    return preturns,pvariances
......
```

Comment: nothing you've shown here will run on the GPU.  You'll need to learn how to use numba CUDA programming if you want to take advantage of the GPU using numba.  It's not a simple matter of changing a few decorators.  A tutorial on how to program the GPU using numba is not reasonable for a SO question, and there are plenty of online resources available.

Comment: As was I though. But, from where am I to start from , to use my GPU, with numba or other module ? thks

Comment: [CuPy](https://cupy.dev/) is much more of a drop-in replacement for NumPy and SciPy than numba is.

Comment: thks John, I'll check it out !

Comment: By the way, note that mainstream PC GPU cards are really inefficient to work on double-precision numbers and Numpy massively use it by default. Thus you should expect a slow down using Cupy unless you reduce the precision (or buy a very expensive server GPU). Additionally, please note that GPUs are good for heavily compute-bound task of to operate on huge array (at least 1 MiB). Otherwise, the latency to send commands to the GPU will be higher than the actual computation.

Comment: For example, your GPU is able to achieve 54-72 GFlops on double precision (DP) and 1.7-2.3 TFlops on simple precision (SP). A 3 year old middle-end CPU like a i5-9600KF succeed to reach 300 GFlops in DP and 600 GFlops in SP in real-world benchmarks. So, this CPU is 6 time faster for DP, but 3-4 times slower for SP assuming the GPU is used at 100%.

Comment: ok, noted. I'm awared about latency variable; what I also noted with LSTM algoritms is a relevant reduction of processing times with GPU than without, with extremely increase of their gap as bigger become the dataset, thus the number of dot products involved.

Comment: that's way I though better to shift to GPU the most as possible functions that involves matrixes and them algebras....least but not last, because I've already payed and now need to return a payoff ffrom the GPU :-))